# LRU c++ program

Tags: c++, lru

I've been working on a program in one of my college classes. I have been having trouble with the implementation of my LRU code as it is not displaying any errors or anything, but compiles. There are two parts. The main that we input the values into, which we then specify which algorithm we want to use to find page faults. I know the main works, along with the FIFO algorithm, but I'm not getting anything with my LRU code (It compiles and "runs" but displays nothing as if I did not click to use the algorithm). Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong?

main.cpp

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string>

//#include "fifo.cpp"
#include "lru.cpp"
//#include "optimal.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // List of different variables
    string pagestring;
    int fs,pn[50], n;

    // Prompt for page references
    cout<<"Virtual Memory Simulation\nBy blah\n----------\nEnter the number of pages : " << endl;
        cin >> n;
    cout<<"\n-------------\nPlease enter a list of page numbers separated by commas.\n"<< endl;
        cin>>pagestring;



    // algorithm to use
    char algo;

    while (true) {
        // Prompt algorithm to use
        cout<<"----------\nPlease select an algorithm to use.\n\n1: First-In-First-Out (FIFO)\n2: Least-Recently-Used (LRU)\n3: Optimal\n0: Quit\n"<<endl;
        cin>>algo;

        if (algo == '1') {
            //fifo(pagestring);
        }
        else if (algo == '2'){
            LRU_Execute(pagestring, n);
        }
        else if (algo == '3'){
            cout<<"Optimal Not yet coded"<<endl;
        }
        else if (algo == '0'){
            break;
        }
        else {
            cout<<"Invalid choice. Please try again."<<endl;
        }

    }

    cout<<"Goodbye!!"<<endl;


};
```

LRU.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class pra
{
int fs,z;
 int  frame[50], frame1[50][2], pn[50], n, cnt, p, x;
public:
 pra();
 void init(string pagestring);
 void getdata(string pagestring, int n);
 void lru(int* pn, int n, string pagestring);

};


pra::pra()
{
 int i;

 for (i = 0; i < fs; i++)
 {
  frame[i] = -1;
 }
 for (i = 0; i < fs; i++)
 {
  frame1[i][0] = -1;
  frame1[i][1] = 0;
 }
 p = 0;
 cnt = 0;
}

void pra::init(string pagestring)
{
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < fs; i++)
 {
  frame[i] = -1;
 }
 for (i = 0; i < fs; i++)
 {
  frame1[i][0] = -1;
  frame1[i][1] = 0;
 }
 p = 0;
 cnt = 0;
}

void pra::getdata(string pagestring, int n)
{
fs=3;


// index to loop through input string
    int i = 0;

    // current input string character
    char z = pagestring[i];
    int x = 0;

//cout << "\nEnter the page numbers : ";
while (z != '\0'){
        // skip over commas and spaces
        if (!(z == ',')) {
              pn[x] = z;
        x++;

//  cout<<pn[x]<<"-This is pn[x]\n";    
}
    z = pagestring[++i];


}
//cout<<pn[x]<<"-This is pn[x] AGAIN\n";
this->lru(pn, n, pagestring);
}

void pra::lru(int* pn, int n, string pagestring)
{
 init(pagestring);
 int ind = 0, fault = 0, pi = 0, j, fn;
 char i, z;
 p = 0;
 cnt = 0;
 int min;
cout<<n<<"---"<<i<<" - "<<j<<" - "<<" - "<<fn<<" - "<<z;
 for (i = 0; i < fs; i++)
 {
  frame1[i][0] = -1;
  frame1[i][1] = 0;
 }
pi = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)

 {
  j = 0;
  if (ind > fs - 1)
   ind = 0;
  fault = 1;
  min = 999;

  while (j < fs)
  {
   if (frame1[j][0] = pn[pi])
   {
    fault = 0;
    p++;
    frame1[j][1] = p;

    goto l2;
   }
   if (frame1[j][1] < min)
   {
    min = frame1[j][1];
    fn = j;
   }
   j++;
  }
  j = 0;
  while (j < fs)
  {
   if (frame1[j][0] = -1)
   {
    fault = 1;
    fn = j;
    goto l2;
   }
   j++;
  }
  ind++;
l2:
  if (fault == 1)
  {
   p++;
   frame1[fn][0] = pn[pi];
   frame1[fn][1] = p;
   cnt++;
  }
  cout << "\nElement: " << pn[pi];
  pi++;
  for (z = 0; z < fs; z++)
  {
   cout << "\t" << frame1[z][0];
  }
  if (fault == 1)
   cout << "\t**Page Fault**";
  else
   cout << "\t--No Page Fault--";
 }
 cout << "\nTotal number of page faults: " << cnt;
 cout << "\n";
}


void LRU_Execute(string pagestring, int n)
{
 pra p;
 int  j, fault = 0, i, pi, z, fn, ind = 0, ans, ch;
 p.getdata(pagestring, n);
 //p.lru();
 while (ans == 1);
 //return 1;
}
```

Comment: What is not happening?  What do you expect?

Comment: No, because you haven't said what the problem is.

Comment: Please see details of [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: sorry! I am supposed to input a string of numbers, separated by commas, to test page fault errors. With the LRU code I have, literally nothing is happening. I can't figure out why, and neither can my group.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code? Step through the code, look at the exact path it's taking based on the input you provide, and then you can isolate it to a particular section of the code and ask a more specific question about that code. We're not here to perform basic debugging services.

Comment: That's the thing. There are zero errors. It compiles fine.

Comment: `pra` doesn't take a string parameter - did you mean `LRU_Execute(pagestring)`? Also you should compile with warnings on, there are a ton of them.

Comment: I've been compiling with g++ main.cpp and haven't received any errors until I tried using LRU_Execute(pagestring) in the main in which I am now receiving a "segmentation fault (core dumped) error.

Comment: Just updated my LRU code. I am no longer getting segmentation faults...It's actually running and executes some data, but displays 0 page faults where I know is supposed to be 3 (input string when asked: 1,2,3,4,5).

Comment: "I have been having trouble with the implementation of my LRU code as it is not displaying any errors or anything, but compiles" Made my day... if you have trouble with compiling code, just remove a random paranthesis or some well selected semikolons. The trouble should go away and you should see your errors immediately. *sorry, next time I will deliver helpful comments again*

Comment: I have made a few changes to my code now. It (seemingly) reads each inputted number but outputs wrong results. Can someone please help me fix my code? I've spent hours tinkering with it. @grek40

Comment: @SeCra After tinkering hours with your code, please spend another 30 minutes tinkering with your question (not only the code part). Pay attention to the hints in the comments here, like [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and take a minute to try it out (pretend you didn't have anything other than the question and reconstruct your problem)